# jquery raty require rating

Tags: jquery, require, raty

I'm trying to figure out how to get the jquery Raty plugin required. Does anyone one know of an easy way just to make sure the user has clicked a star. if anyone need to see anyone part of code please ask me. I'm not to great with jquery yet so please be detailed and thank you.

```
    $rates.raty({
        half: false,
        target : '#add_post_rating',
        hints: pixreviews.hints,
        path: path,
        targetKeep : true,
        //targetType : 'score',
        targetType : 'hint',
        //precision  : true,
        score: default_rating,
        scoreName: 'pixrating',
        click: function(rating, evt) {

            $('#add_post_rating' ).val( '' + rating );
            $('#add_post_rating option[value="' + rating + '"]' ).attr(  'selected', 'selected' );

        },
        starType : 'i'
    });
```

Comment: this seams to be the way to go `$('div').raty('score');` from [jQuery Raty - Functions](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty#functions)

Comment: where should i put this

Comment: _"Does anyone one know of an easy way just to make sure the user has clicked a star"_...   so, depending on where you need to check this... or what event "trigger your question" for example onclick, beforeClose.

Comment: i need to require the user to give a rating before allowing them to submit, and through an error if no rating is given.

Answer (score 2):

Because you defined:

```
scoreName: 'pixrating'
```

Raty will create an input type hidden field inside the div. You need to consider this field.

My example and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jddawtv/):

```js
$(function () {
  $('div').raty({
    half: false,
    hints: ['bad', 'poor', 'regular', 'good', 'gorgeous'],
    path: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wbotelhos/raty/master/lib/images/',
    targetKeep: true,
    //targetType : 'score',
    targetType: 'hint',
    //precision  : true,
    score: 0,
    scoreName: 'pixrating',
    click: function (rating, evt) {
      $('#add_post_rating').val(rating);
    },
    starType: 'i'
  });

  // handle the select box changes
  $('#add_post_rating').on('change', function (e) {
    $('div input[name="pixrating"]').val(this.value);
    $('div').raty('score', this.value);
  }).trigger('change');

  // on form submit do your test....
  $('#frm').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ($('div').raty('score') == '0') {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('error: raty is 0!');
      return;
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/wbotelhos/raty/master/lib/jquery.raty.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wbotelhos/raty/master/lib/jquery.raty.js"></script>

<form id="frm">
    <div></div>
    <select id="add_post_rating">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```